# Get file input value to simulate form post using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-s3

I have a javascript function which is submitting a form post to upload an image to s3 using simple httppost, the form works fine with submit but I want to use ajax which i'm finding the file input is not submitted as I'm using the value field. I am trying to grab it with files[0] but that's empty..

Does an httppost submit the entire file, do I need to read the contents of the file or just post the url using ajax as the value of the file field?! this doesn't seem to be working.

I'd prefer ajax because when I use a normal submit it refreshes the entire page and redirects the user. I want to send the file to s3 and intercept the xml response from s3 using ajax without a browser refresh.

It seems the file contents aren't loaded until the submit action is performed so the content of the file is not available until form submit, how to trigger this from javascript? I'm not using jquery so I'm figuring how to get the file contents as a post variable to post from javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `POST` `File` or `Blob` object directly by setting either instance at `body` at `fetch()` call,  or append `File` object to `FormData` object and `POST` `multipart/form-data` to server.

```
document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
.onchange = e => {
  if (e.target.files.length)
    fetch("/path/to/server", {
      method:"POST",
      body:e.target.files[0]
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response.ok))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }
}
```

Comment: I managed to do this with formdata which seems to have better browser support. Thanks.